# Lines in seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn

What are these lines in seaborn plots? And why does some point have these lines and some don't?

[image]

Here is the code:

```
# grid = sns.FacetGrid(train_df, col='Embarked')
grid = sns.FacetGrid(train_df, row='Embarked', size=3.5, aspect=2.0)
grid.map(sns.pointplot, 'Pclass', 'Survived', 'Sex', palette='deep')
grid.add_legend()
```

And here is the screen shot of the data used:

[image]

Pclass only has values: 1, 2, 3

Embarked has: 'S', 'C', 'Q'

Sex: 'female', 'male'

Survived: 1, 0

Comment: Please, if you can, share the source code.

Comment: Are the data points averages? Because if so, the lines could be the range of the data

Comment: They are confidence intervals drawn from boostrapping your data. Are you using catplot? You can change it to None using estimator parameter to see no line at all. Refer to the documentation: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html#seaborn.catplot